# How can I open my bottom-hung windows for cleaning?

Tags: windows, cleaning

I have smaller bottom-hung windows above my regular ones. They open just a little and are held in place with this mechanism:

[image]
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbc9Y.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNAtx.jpg

What is the best way to open them a bit further so that they can be cleaned?

Edit: I succeeded in unhinging one of them at the bottom, to be able to better access the mechanism on the right. Second pic is of unhinged, now bottom-opened, window.

Comment: It's hard to see from the underexposed photo, but I wonder if the dark clip towards the upper right would release the silver bar and allow you to swing that downward and release it from the slot while oriented horizontally. It may have an oblong retainer that locks into the large vertical slot when it's not horizontal.

Comment: I am thinking theses are an awning window? At first I thought you were referring to a single hung window....

Comment: @isherwood You're right about the oblong retainer. But the little clip won't budge, in fact it's fixed with a spiked ring underneath to prevent it turning. I'm still trying to move the silver bar anyway ...

Comment: @Jack They are single hung, I just unhinged one for the new picture.